# Is there a way to bundle native ECMAScript modules?

Tags: javascript

I wonder if there a standard way to bundle native ES modules.

Suppose I have such a "brilliant" project (just for example):

```
<!-- index.html -->
<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>

// main.js
import value from "./lib.js"

console.log(value);

// lib.js
export default 'hello world';
```

Now it needs three requests to load — it's too much, I need only two — .html and .js.

It looks simple at first glance (`cat *.js > bundle.js`) but there is no syntax for multiple ES modules in one file (as I can see).

I know I can translate ES modules syntax to some other module system (e. g. AMD) and then bundle them but it isn't what I want.

I am curious to accomplish this by native module features only. As simple and handmade as possible.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe at least a proposal?

Thank you.

Comment: With the advent of HTTP/2 and its ability to pipeline and multiplex requests, the need for bundling is much reduced. What was mentioned in [How do you build, bundle & minify ES6-modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45400636/215552) holds true even today.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree that HTTP/2 have reduced the significance of bundling. But not ultimately. From my point of view, bundling is still a very important part of client-side module system, I was surprised there does not exist something similar in ES spec.

Answer (score 2):

[rollup](https://rollupjs.org) supports ESM as an output format as well. Your example [transpiles](https://rollupjs.org/repl?version=1.2.1&shareable=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) to a simple script, but if you have exports in your entry module it will keep them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the example! Rollup build an one ESM from my modules, am I correct? What about module isolation (in more complex system)?

Comment: What do you mean by "module isolation", that a single file could contain multiple module sources that could be imported individually? I do not know of any such file format, on the web HTTP/2 is supposed to solve this.

Comment: (It can build an ESM, but...) you use the bundle in a `<script>`, it doesn't need to be a module. Even if it `export`ed something, it's not like another script is `import`ing it

Comment: Create another simple example (bit.ly/2tsr9Ry). As I expected, isolation is made via some ugly tricks. :(

Comment: @Bergi I have posted an example above. Sorry for the tricky link, the data url was too long. :( The example consist of two modules, both have a top-level variables with the same name.

Comment: @shau-kote Ah, yes, Rollup properly conserves the specified module behaviour concerning scopes, hoisting, evaluation order etc. using the usual transpiler tricks.

Answer (score 1):

`rollup`, `webpack` etc natively understand and can bundle ES modules.